# change vertical gap between two paragraphs

Tags: spacing

I only need to change the white gap between two paragraphs in a particular spot in my thesis. In particular I want to reduce the vertical white space. I know that I can do `\\[5pt]` to add more space. So I tried `\\[-5pt]`. But it did not work. Is there a quick way to just reduce the vertical white space between paragraphs.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that shows the problem. Do you want to reduce space between paragraphs in general or in one particular spot? You could try `\vspace{-5pt}` if it is just in one place but it is usually better to find a more systematic solution.

Comment: This should be possible by changing `\parskip`

Comment: Never end a paragraph with `\\ ` (whether positive or negative optional argument) `<blank line>\vspace{-5cm}` should work.

Answer (score 15):

To reduce the white space between paragraphs:

```
Paragraph1 text text

\vspace{-5pt}

Paragraph 2 text text
```

Comment: You might like to say _where_ that has to go (eg by copying the rest of the above comment) also in an answer perhaps a more normal value might be better.

Comment: You can put this between the paragraphs. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes but the behaviour is quite different depending whether or not you have the blank line before or after the `\vspace`. (normally you want it before, or both before and after, which is the same)